# Setting up periodic tasks in Celery (celerybeat) dynamically using add_periodic_task

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, celery, celerybeat

I'm using `Celery 4.0.1` with `Django 1.10` and I have troubles scheduling tasks (running a task works fine). Here is the celery configuration:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
app = Celery('myapp')

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

app.conf.BROKER_URL = 'amqp://{}:{}@{}'.format(settings.AMQP_USER, settings.AMQP_PASSWORD, settings.AMQP_HOST)
app.conf.CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'myapp.celery'
app.conf.CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'myapp.celery_default'
app.conf.CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
app.conf.CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
app.conf.CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
app.conf.CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
app.conf.BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 2

app.conf.CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('myapp.celery_default'),
    Queue('myapp.queue1'),
    Queue('myapp.queue2'),
    Queue('myapp.queue3'),
)
```

Then in tasks.py I have:

```
@app.task(queue='myapp.queue1')
def my_task(some_id):
    print("Doing something with", some_id)
```

In views.py I want to schedule this task:

```
def my_view(request, id):
    app.add_periodic_task(10, my_task.s(id))
```

Then I execute the commands:

```
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq.service
celery -A myapp.celery_app beat -l debug
celery worker -A myapp.celery_app
```

But the task is never scheduled. I don't see anything in the logs. The task is working because if in my view I do:

```
def my_view(request, id):
    my_task.delay(id)
```

The task is executed.

If in my configuration file if I schedule the task manually, like this it works:

```
app.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': 10.0,
        'args': (66,)
    },
}
```

I just can't schedule the task dynamically. Any idea?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## EDIT: (13/01/2018)

> *The latest [release 4.1.0](http://www.celeryproject.org/news/celery-410-released/) have addressed the subject in this [ticket #3958](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3958) and has been merged*

---

Actually you can't not define periodic task at the view level, because the beat schedule setting will be loaded first and can not be rescheduled at runtime:

> The [`add_periodic_task()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/base.html#Celery.add_periodic_tas) function will add the entry to the beat_schedule setting behind the scenes, and the same setting can also can be used to set up periodic tasks manually:
>
> ```
> app.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
>     'add-every-30-seconds': {
>         'task': 'tasks.my_task',
>         'schedule': 10.0,
>         'args': (66,)
>     },
> }
> ```

which means if you want to use `add_periodic_task()` it should be wrapped within an `on_after_configure` handler at the celery app level and any modification on runtime will not take effect:

```
app = Celery()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(10, my_task.s(66))
```

As mentioned in the [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes) the the regular celerybeat simply keep track of task execution:

> The default scheduler is the [`celery.beat.PersistentScheduler`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/beat.html#PersistentScheduler), that simply keeps track of the last run times in a local shelve database file.

In order to be able to dynamically manage periodic tasks and reschedule celerybeat at runtime:

> There’s also the [django-celery-beat](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension that stores the schedule in the Django database, and presents a convenient admin interface **to manage periodic tasks at runtime**.

The tasks will be persisted in django database and the scheduler could be updated in task model at the db level. Whenever you update a periodic task a counter in this tasks table will be incremented, and tells the celery beat service to reload the schedule from the database.

A possible solution for you could be as follow:

```
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule

schedule= IntervalSchedule.objects.create(every=10, period=IntervalSchedule.SECONDS)
task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(interval=schedule, name='any name', task='tasks.my_task', args=json.dumps([66]))
```

**views.py**

```
def update_task_view(request, id)
    task = PeriodicTask.objects.get(name="task name") # if we suppose names are unique
    task.args=json.dumps([id])
    task.save()
```

Comment: Picking up on your comment "Actually you can't not define periodic task at the view level": Is it possible to use `add_periodic_task()` at the app-level, i.e. in`task.py`? It seems better encapsulation to keep these periodic tasks declared within the app.

Comment: Actually is not at all necessary to use it, as it will be called for you if you just use `app.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` settings syntax, but if you want use it explicitly you  can use it in the `task.py` file.

Comment: I believe the latest release(after 4.1.0) should have this one addressed. Here is the dev that is going on [#3958](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3958)

Comment: Note that `on_after_configure` will not work for periodic tasks defined in a `tasks.py` file in another app.  Use `on_after_finalize` instead.  This is because the `on_after_configure` signal is sent once the `celery.py` file is imported, but the `autodiscover_tasks` call is not resolved until much later, when django is done setting up all of the apps.  (`autodiscover_tasks` schedules that call but does not execute it immediately unless you use `force=True` which is guaranteed to fail with Django).